# Jquery.Validation IE and FF issue

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jqueryform

hello guys i'm having an issue with the jquery validation plugin. the code works fine in `chrome` and `Opera` while not in EI version `10.0.xx`  and FF version `23.xx` 
whenever i click the button to submit the form it wont work

```
     <script src="style/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="style/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            var kosh = document.getElementById("username").value;
            $("#form").validate({
                rules:{
                    full_name:"required",
                    user_name:"required",
                    secret:"required",
                    user_email:{
                            required:true,
                            email: true
                        },
                    pwd:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength: 8
                    },
                    cpwd:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo: "#pwd"
                    },
                    gender:"required",
                    privacy:"required"
                },
                messages:{
                    full_name:"Enter your first and last name",
                    user_name:"Please Chose a Username",
                    secret:"Your Secret Word Can't Be Empty",
                    user_email:{
                        required:"Enter your email address",
                        email:"Enter valid email address"
                    },
                    pwd:{
                        required:"Enter your password",
                        minlength:"Password must be minimum 8 characters"
                    },
                    cpwd:{
                        required:"Enter confirm password",
                        equalTo:"Password and Confirm Password must match"
                    },
                    gender:"Select Gender",
                    privacy:"Select How you like to share your photos with others"
                },
                errorClass: "help-inline",
                errorElement: "span",
                highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
                }
            });         
$('document').ready(function()
{
$('#form').ajaxForm( {
target: '#preview', 
success: function() { 
$('#formbox').slideUp('fast'); 
} 
}); 
$('#loginForm').ajaxForm( {
target: '#preview', 
success: function() { 
$('#formbox').slideUp('fast'); 
} 
});
});

        });
      </script>
```

and my form as follow

```
          <form action="func/login.php" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right">

          <input required class="input-large" name="user" placeholder="Your Username..." type="text">
          <input  required type="password" name="pass"  placeholder="Your Password" class="input-large">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Login !</button>
        <a href="reset.php"><span style="color:#fff; position:relative; top:3px; align:center; font-family:verdana;padding:3px; font-size:10px">Forgot Password?</span></a>
      </form>
```

lets say if i typed the wrong username and password it actually returns the result but whenever the username and password are correct it doesn't get the result from the php script which if username and password are correct it automatically load the `index.php` but it wont load it but i already signed in, if i typed the `index.php` to the url bar

Answer (score 0):

fix it by replacing

```
echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php">';
```

to

```
echo'<script>document.location.href="index.php"</script>';
```

which i don't know why FF and IE wont accept the meta tag